# jQuery focus event is never triggered

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus

I have parent element `<ul class="dropdown-menu big">` that contains child elements like `<li><input class="contact-form"></li>`. I want to apply some css styles on parent element if one of the inputs are focused, for example change background color:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   $(".contact-form").focus(function(){
      $(".dropdown-menu.big").css('background-color', '#ff5544');
   });

});
```

But this code does nothing, nothing happens on focus event and no error is shown in Chrome debugger.

**Edit:** Space from selector removed, but nothing changed.

---

**Edit:** Problem is, that focus event is never triggered. I changed my code to `alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");` and no alert is shown. Why is that?

Comment: `$(".dropdown-menu.big")` remove the space in your selector.

Comment: It doesn't help, nothing happens again.

Comment: _I want to apply some css styles on parent element_ what is it `li` or `ul`.

Comment: `$(".dropdown-menu.big").css('background', '#ff5544');` try with `background`.

Comment: It is <ul>, and 'background' also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Either you remove the space :

```
$(".dropdown-menu.big").css('background', '#ff5544');
```

or get it through focussed element by DOM traversal:

```
$(this).closest(".dropdown-menu.big").css('background', '#ff5544');
```

---

and one more suggestion is instead of `background-color` just use `background`

checkout the snippet below: ↓

```js
$(':text').focus(function() {
  $(".dropdown.big").addClass('newclass');
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: greenyellow;
}
.dropdown{ background:red !important;}

.newclass{background:purple !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='dropdown big'>
  <li>
    <input type='text' />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: None of that works for me. There is a default style defined in css file. What is of higher priority - css styles in .css file or styles set by jQuery?

Comment: if `!important` css hack is used in styles then it will get that instead of applied one with js. so you can try adding `!important` in a new class and add the class to the element:`.addClass('newclass')`.

Answer (score 1):

here's a working fiddle, background applied to the parent li + blur function remove it: https://jsfiddle.net/RexTangle4/o9Lsb91n/

jquery:

```
$('.contact-form').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().css({
        backgroundColor: '#ff5544'
    });
}).blur(function(){
     $(this).parent().css({
        backgroundColor: ''
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it works in fiddle, but it does not work in my tempalate.

Comment: does the li have visible area around the input? (it may not if it is display inline-block and has no padding), also, an important tag will overwrite the inline style, so is there anything in the CSS that's getting in the way?

Comment: yes, but i figured out that focus event is never triggered, I dont know why, script is loaded properly.

Comment: no errors on page load, no errors on input focus, script is loaded properly.. weird.

Comment: do hover/click events work? or no event at all (eg just an alert inside the doc ready)

Answer (score 0):

try use style instead of css like this

```
$(".dropdown-menu.big").focus(function () {
this.style.backgroundColor("red");
    });
```

and make sure you put and  use true jquery file like this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was very stupid, I had spelling mistake in input class - 'contact-from' instead of 'contact-form'.